# Google Maps Api StreetView events visible_changed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a bit of a problem using the visible_changed listener, hopefully I am using it correctly...

Basically what I am trying to do, is that when you drop the Pegman on the map, look for the nearest marker, and point the street view heading there. I ONLY want this to happen each time Street view is loaded, so I figured I would be able to capture that with the visible_changed listener. The problem is this seems to also be firing each time the street view camera position changes, instead of only each time the street view window becomes visible. Am I just doing this wrong, is there a different listener event I should be capturing?

```js
// Street View Events

var thePanorama = map.getStreetView();

google.maps.event.addListener(thePanorama, 'visible_changed', function() {

  if (thePanorama.getVisible()) {

    //Street view loads

    //enlarge markers to make them show betetr in street view
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      var oldIcon = gmarkers[i].getIcon(); 
      var newIcon = {url: oldIcon.url, scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 102)};
      gmarkers[i].setIcon(newIcon);
    }


    //Get nearest visible marker
    var nearestMarker = gmarkers.reduce(function (prev, curr) {

      if (curr.getVisible()) {

        var cpos = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(thePanorama.position, curr.position);
        var ppos = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(thePanorama.position, prev.position);

        return cpos < ppos ? curr : prev;

      }
      else{

        return prev;

      } 

    })


    var path = [thePanorama.getPosition(), nearestMarker.getPosition()];
    var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(path[0], path[1]);

    //point the street view heading
    thePanorama.setPov({
      heading: heading,
      pitch: 0
    });




  }
  else{

    //Street view unloaded, return markers to original size

    alert(thePanorama.getVisible())

    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      var oldIcon = gmarkers[i].getIcon(); 
      var newIcon = {url: oldIcon.url, scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 34)};
      gmarkers[i].setIcon(newIcon);
    }

  }

})
```

Here is an update with minimal code - I expect this event to fire each time street view is loaded or unloaded, but it also fires each time the street view camera changes position. Is there any way to only capture then street view loads and unloads?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
//This event is also firing when the POV camera moves, and shouldn't be.            
google.maps.event.addListener(map.getStreetView(),'visible_changed',function(){
alert('streetview is ' +(this.getVisible()?'open':'closed'));
});
      }
      
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewEvents):

> visible_changed fires whenever the Street View's visibility changes. Note that this event may fire asynchronously after a change in the pano ID indicated through pano_changed.

That doesn't stop you from filtering only the open and close events though. You can hold the previous visibility state of the streetview and fire the event only if the current state is different from previous state. Here you go:

```js
window.initMap = function () {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  var isVisible = false;
  google.maps.event.addListener(map.getStreetView(), 'visible_changed', function() {
    var visible = this.getVisible();
    if (isVisible != visible) {
      alert('streetview is ' + (visible ? 'open' : 'closed'));
    }
    isVisible = visible;
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sirkurt53/3wnLppxw/)

Comment: Perfect - I don't know why I didn't think about storing the last state. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first event, use [addListenerOnce](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event):

Change:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(thePanorama, 'visible_changed', function() {
```

To:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(thePanorama, 'visible_changed', function() {
```

Comment: Well, I don't just want the first event, I should have been a little clearer. I want to catch each time Streetview is initiated, so I can point the camera to the nearest marker each time. This code is just firing once when the map first loads.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I think I have a pretty complete code example, it is my entire listener function.... I laid out what I expect it to do, and what is actually happening. Is there something else I should add?

Comment: The posted code (when I add the missing stuff) alerts "false".  Not sure how you "tested" your [mcve].

Comment: Ok - I edited my answer, and provided an example complete with the extras - It's been awhile since I've been on SO, there wasn't inline, runnable code a couple of years ago. Hopefully my edit is more clear, thank you for your help.